# set border of UITextView ios

Tags: uitextview, border, layer, shadow

I have a program:

```
            [textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:20]];
            [textView setEditable:NO];
            [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
            [textView.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
            [textView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
            [textView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
            textView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
            textView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
            textView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
            [textView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
```

this code set a shadow and border for a UITextView, but how can i set border of textview not include top line , only set border for left, right and bottom line ?

Comment: You can shift the Textfield to make the top border won't appear or use an UIImage to cover that part of border.

Comment: yes, can do like that to hide the top line, but i think it is not a good solution

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want, and it is ridiculously simple to use and integrate: https://github.com/99centsappdevelopment/JSTextView